# How can I perform client and server side validation on a Bootstrap form?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am new to the world of bootstrap and have been using PHP in the past (not advanced) but I saw some great themes on theme forest and a lot of them to be bootstrap. I really like the look of it and downloaded a template. However, they aren't very easy to edit.

That being said, I have a newsletter signup and I want to perform validation on it that brings up an error message if you leave blank or don't type in an email address. I believe that client side and server side would be best. From what I have read, for the client side you can use jQuery? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for the form:

```
<section class="strip bg-primary">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mail-list-signup" id="form1">
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pull-left clear-fix">
                            <h3 class="text-white pull-left"><strong>Get Notified.&nbsp;</strong></h3>
                            <input name="email" type="text" class="signup-email-field" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email here here">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-right text-right">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-filled" value="Subscribe">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
            <iframe class="mail-list-form" srcdoc="">
            </iframe>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `required` to your input

```
<input name="email" type="text" class="signup-email-field" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email here here" required>
```

This will popup a message if empty.

**or**

if you wanted to define in jquery,

```
$(document).on('click','[type="submit"]', function() {
    var $value = $('#email').val();

    if($value === "" || $value === null)
    {
         $('#id_to_red_message').html("Empty Email");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. However, neither method works. If I try the first one nothing happens and if I try the jquery, Dreamweaver says there is an error with the code, i.e.: the last }

Comment: @ChandreshRM you forgot to close the onclick with `);`

Comment: Thank you! This works but it isn't exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, I should have explained better. I don't want an actual pop-up. I wanted some red text to appear in the text box or under it with a message. I especially like it when the text box actually goes red. Sorry for not being more specific in my initial post.

Comment: @Jonathan I have updated the code..FYI, this is an example...u can added whatever u want in error part... `$('#email').css('outline','red');`...so please try

Comment: Thanks so much. Will try asap and let you know.